# Why is updateCorrelator not updating new location on my ads?

Tags: javascript, ajax, ads, google-dfp

I have a page where I reload most of the page with AJAX, including a couple ads, on a page click.  This page click often changes the location targeting (i.e., the user clicks the 'Texas' button).  So, on the part of the page that is loaded with AJAX, I'd like to update the ads with the new location.

In the docs on [updateCorrelator](https://developers.google.com/doubleclick-gpt/reference#googletag.PubAdsService_updateCorrelator), I am given the impression that I can use this on an AJAX load to update my ads with a new location using the [setLocation](https://developers.google.com/doubleclick-gpt/reference#googletag.PubAdsService_setLocation) function.  I see in my console that both `updateCorrelator` and `setLocation` are being called before the [refresh](https://developers.google.com/doubleclick-gpt/reference#googletag.PubAdsService_refresh) function refreshes the ad on the AJAX page update.  However, unless I actual do a manual refresh of the whole page, the ads I am loading are targeting the old location still.

How can I display ads using the new location parameters without refreshing the whole page?

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.